# Python: My global variable is not defined

Tags: python, variables

im trying to create a registerFunction that will save the users username and password to a list. However when i call username_list (which is in the readFunction) in a while loop, I receive the error that "username_list is not defined"

```
def readFunction(): #--------------------------------------------------readFunction
    username_read = open('username_db.csv', 'r')
    global username_list
    username_list = [n.replace("\n","") for n in username_read.readlines()]#<<<-------------------------Where the variable is created is produced
    username_read.close()

    password_read = open('password_db.csv', 'r')
    global password_list
    password_list = [n.replace("\n", "") for n in password_read.readlines()]
    password_read.close()


def registerFunction(): #----------------------------------------------registerFunction
    print("\nRegister - Please enter your details below\n")
    username = input("Enter a Username: ")
    password = input("Enter a Password: ")
    passwordConfirm = input("Confirm your password: ")

    while username in username_list: #<<<-------------------------Where the error is produced
        print("Sorry, this username is already in use")
        username = input("Enter a Username: ")
    else:
        username_list.append(username)
        password_list.append(password)
        print("Your account has been successfully created")
```

Comment: Don't use global variable when you don't really need it, make the readFunction return the `username_list` and pass it to the regiterFunction as parameter

Comment: Have you called `readFunction`? `username_list` won't actually exist until its first assignment.

Comment: If you know the problem is that your global variable is not defined, why don’t you define the global variable, then?

Comment: Thanks tdelaney, originally I tried calling the readFunction above where i call the mainFunction, but it didnt work, so i just tried to call it inside of the registerFunction and it worked!

Azro, im quite new to python as this is the first program i am making, im afraid i dont yet know how to do what it is you are asking

Comment: MisterMiyagi the variable is defined, it just wasent called inside of the registerFunction. I thought making it a global variable would allow the variable to be used without calling the function